# It's correct to wait a socket answer in a intentService?

Tags: java, android, sockets, service, client

I've create a tcp socket with a thread and it works well. Now I need to send a request to server and to listen it. It could answer me after 100 seconds. So I've thought to use an asynctask, but 100 second are a lot...
So I use an IntentService in a class (this class is private because there is in an other class):

```
  public class Generate extends Fragment
{  
 /*  *** 
 the code about of my app
      ***  */

private class Position extends IntentService
{

    public Position()
    {
        super("Position");
    }
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
           socket.setSoTimeout(100000);
           PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
           out.write("TX_DATA");

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1000];


            StringBuilder reader = new StringBuilder();

            int numRead = 0;
            if ((numRead = socket.getInputStream().read(bytes)) >= 0)
            {
                reader.append(new String(bytes, 0, numRead));
            }

            if(reader.toString().equals("RX_DATA"))
             getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Data received",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             });


        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   }
```

but..it's correct to do how I need to? I need to wait 100 second, listen the answers of the server, upgrade the UI and close the service...
How this intentservice works?
Thank you for the answers

Comment: Using AsyncTask is one way to achieve that. I believe later versions of Android don't let you do any network operations on the main thread anyway, so some form of thread or asynchronous pattern is required. 100 seconds is of no concern it's just if you need to update or inform the user of progress within that time.

Comment: So could I use an asynctask ?

Comment: Yes. You just have to consider the benefits of using an AsyncTask compared to a Thread object, for example, or any other means of doing an asynchronous task at your disposal. That's of course dependent upon your application.

Comment: Ok :) But if I would my app works on background, I can't use an asynctask, sure?

Comment: I think you can, even though you're running in background. However I jsut note from the AsyncTask API it's best suited to tasks of only a few seconds, which I never realised/. perhaps it's changed. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: So I can create a service and put an asynctask in this,sure?

Comment: @Kerry: "100 seconds is of no concern" -- yes, it is. Please see my answer.

Comment: I did mean that 100 seconds is of no concern as it's not on the main thread i.e. blocking any GUI action. In that respect as long as a long running task is NOT put on the main thread then the length of time is of no concern. Naturally, defensive programming would dictate the handling of the unforseen, but that's whether the second task runs for 1 second or 100 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> So I've thought to use an asynctask, but 100 second are a lot

Yes. In particular, if the user leaves your app (e.g., BACK, HOME), there is a chance that Android will terminate your process before your work is complete.

> So I use an IntentService

That is better than an `AsyncTask` in this case. If you have background work that will take longer than a couple of seconds, having that background work be managed by a service increases the likelihood that your process will be around long enough to complete that work.

For 100+ seconds, you also have the issue of the device falling asleep before your work is complete. You will need to use a `WakeLock` (perhaps via [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful)) and perhaps a `WifiLock` to ensure that everything stays stable.

Comment: Thanks,I see it after...but how can I listen the server for 100 seconds? I need to implement a broadcast receiver?

Comment: @Francesca: "but how can I listen the server for 100 seconds?" -- you already have code for a 100-second timeout. "I need to implement a broadcast receiver?" -- not that I am aware of. If your question is "how do I get the results of the socket call to my UI?", use an event bus implementation (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, Square's Otto, etc.).

Comment: @Francesca: `runOnUiThread()` is a method on `Activity`. You do not have an `Activity` in a `Service`.

Comment: Ok thanks :) but I have a trouble now: I want to listen server message when my application is closed...how can I do it? Intentservice doesn't work when application is closed, sure?

Comment: @Francesca: Keeping the CPU on all the time will drastically cut the user's battery life. While an `IntentService` can run "when application is closed", something needs to trigger it to run. If you want to ask your server for messages once an hour, use `AlarmManager`. If you expect to be able to receive messages at any point, switch to Google Cloud Messaging, so you do not need to continuously poll the server.

Comment: I know of this battery cut. So you tell me to don't keep app in background to listen server?

Comment: @Francesca: I am telling you not to keep the CPU powered on to listen to your server. That means you need to either infrequently poll the server, switch to Google Cloud Messaging, or invest a several dozen developer-months in creating your own power-friendly push notification system.

Comment: @Francesca: Then encrypt the data.

Comment: Ok thank you :) I have only one question: I've implemented tcp connection in a thread..it's correct or it's better to do it in a intentservice too?